# Laravel Passport createerrorToken()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and trying to create an access token from my user model with Laravel passport.

When I select my user and send the request by postman I encounter this error:

> The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.

My request:

```
domain.com/api/login?username=admin&password=admin&email=info@example.com
```

user model:

```php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HybridRelations, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
//        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

and my controller:

```
 public function login(Request $request){
        $user = User::where('password',md5($request->password))
            ->where('email',$request->email)
            ->first();
        if($user){
            $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
            dd($token);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using graphql?

Comment: No. i dont. . .